# Nasm error; undefined labels

Tags: assembly, windows-10, nasm, assemble

This period of time I am trying to learn assembly. I used the ms-dos "debug" command to create simple programs but now I want to make large programs. I downloaded nasm and tried to assemble the following code:

```
.model small
.code
    mov ax, bx
```

But in the labels .model and .code it says that they ar undefined. I tried this again in a couple of other assemblers and the same thing has happened. Can anyone help me with this problem?
I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Your syntax(directives) looks more like MASM than NASM.

Comment: @zx485 how would be the syntax in nasm?

Comment: I suspect you're still making 16-bit code.  You don't have to do that, you can write 32 or 64-bit code in asm that can run natively on 64-bit Windows, and use the normal libraries / Win32 API.  And you can write functions you can call from normal C++ programs.  So you don't have to use DOSBOX or anything like that.  See some of the links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nasm syntax for your program:

```
segment code 
..start: 
mov ax, bx
```

special symbol ..start marks the entry point to your program.
[Here](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html) is a nice manual on writing 16-bit code in Nasm

Regarding `.model small` - there are no memory models in Nasm, citate from documentation at http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html:

> NASM also does not have any directives to support different 16-bit
>   memory models. The programmer has to keep track of which functions are
>   supposed to be called with a far call and which with a near call, and
>   is responsible for putting the correct form of RET instruction (RETN
>   or RETF; NASM accepts RET itself as an alternate form for RETN); in
>   addition, the programmer is responsible for coding CALL FAR
>   instructions where necessary when calling external functions, and must
>   also keep track of which external variable definitions are far and
>   which are near.

And I suggest you to read [Nasm documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/) - there are answers to most of your questions.